# Endermen Not Spawning!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing and defeating the Ender Dragon and respawning it. For some reason Endermen are not spawning, even in "The End"!

Is this a glitch or bug and if not can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: What is your difficulty? If it is on peaceful, that is your problem

Comment: I went on easy mode and they dont spawn that was my problem i went to hard mode and it still doesn't spawn
Im still researching

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't spawning in the End only and you're not on Peaceful, log out of the game and delete your `world_the_end` folder in that save. If they aren't spawning in any world, back up your saves and delete your entire .minecraft folder and reinstall. You might have a mod that is preventing endermen spawning.